# Is there any good book for Boost library C++ and for Object Oriented Design in C++?

Tags: c++, boost

This post is about 2 questions in one:

1. Good books for Boost C++ library
2. OO Design in C++. I come from Java background and tend to think in terms of Interfaces, Singletons etc. How do I translate it to C++ or how to start thinking differently for C++

-Ajay

Comment: Do not try to apply your Java knowledge to this language. You will bring only pain and suffering.

Comment: With rare exceptions, singletons are generally frowned upon, so "thinking in terms of singletons" is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @FredOverflow: And that's true in Java as well as C++. :)

Comment: I know. I don't use it that much. That was just an example. Probably a bad one.

Answer (score 8):

For #1, "[Beyond the C++ Standard Library: An Introduction to Boost](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544)" and "[C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and Beyond](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=boost+c%2B%2B&x=0&y=0)".

Answer (score 7):

for boost: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/ 
I have only just peeked at it, but it is free for on-line browsing, so worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

1. The Boost Graph Library: User Guide and Reference Manual by Jeremy G. Siek, Lie-Quan Lee, and Andrew Lumsdaine
2. Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied (Andrei Alexandrescu)

Answer (score 3):

Some good books are :

Thinking in C++
Effective C++, More Effective C++
Modern C++ Design
Design Patterns

However to evolve towards being a better C++ programmer, you may have to rethink the paradigm of OO as the only approach. This opinion is controversial, but some really smart guys (like Alex Stepanov who created the STL) subscribe to this view.
Modern C++ code relies on generics and template meta-programming more than OO. With the inclusion of Lambdas into the C++0x standard you can push that even further.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the ones mentioned here, I would recommend

Effective STL by Scott Meyers

C++ Gems, edited by Stanley Lippman, contains selected columns from C++ report.

C++ Gotchas by Stephen Dewhurst

Besides these if you are looking for a online source of good C/C++ writing, try Dan Saks columns here

http://www.embedded.com/columns/archive/?content_type=pp

Answer (score 2):

Just case on the market:

[Introduction to Boost C++ Libraries: Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9491028014)

Also 2nd volume coming out later this year:

[Introduction to Boost C++ Libraries: Volume 2](http://datasim-press.com/BoostVolumeII.html)